# how do we send emails and sms after saving data using breeze

Tags: breeze, durandal, asp.net-spa

How do we send email and sms after saving the data using breeze. It is working fine with saving information in database, but i need to do some more operations after saving data. Can anyone help me solve this issue.

```
var saveChanges = function () {
   return manager.saveChanges()
     .then(saveSucceeded)
     .fail(saveFailed);    
    function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
    log('Saved data successfully', saveResult, true);
  }

  function saveFailed(error) {
    var msg = 'Save failed: ' + getErrorMessages(error);
   logError(msg, error);
   error.message = msg;
   throw error;
  }
};

public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
   return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From everything I have seen Breeze and Durandal are not the droids you are looking for...  They are both JavaScript libraries and you cannot send an e-mail from the browser, that I know of.

You need to do an Ajax call or something back to your controller to send an e-mail with your controller or from C# -

[Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail?rq=1)

As @Pawel also pointed out, if you intercept the save in your controller, you could also trigger an e-mail there.

Comment: Thank you kadumel. You mean after calling the saveChanges.. we need to call other ajax function to send email..  am i correct?

Comment: Somewhere in your JavaScript you need to do an Ajax post back to a controller that fires off a function to send an e-mail.  That is my recommendation at least

Comment: You can override DbContextProvider.SaveChangesCore and send email or sms when save operation was successful.